# How to remove 8080 from url on IIS Manager?

Tags: windows, iis, url-rewriting, server

I decided to change the port from 80 to 8080 on IIS manager in Windows Server,

before i change the port when i type "http://localhost/thenameofmywebsite" it was redirecting to my website but after i change the port I have to use "http://localhost:8080/thenameofmywebsite" I think default listening port 80 but i could not find how to change the defaul listening port 8080 with IIS Manager.

Now I want to enter to the website without typing 8080 afer localhost.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want with a reverse proxy in IIS, but that proxy will have to run on port 80 for you to be able to not have to specify a fully qualified socket.

The ability for browsers to resolve "http://name_without_port" as "http://name:80" is a detail of their implementations.

You can't change that behavior without changing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

When ports are **not specified** for HTTP service, **browsers use the default port**, which is 80. Similarly, the default for HTTPS is port 443.

If you are running service on any other ports, you **must** specify it in the URL. So the behavior you are observing is expected, and is normal.

Another question could be why you want to run service on 8080 (as opposed to 80), and that has different set of considerations.